# MySQL error "invalid use of group function error code : 1111"

Tags: mysql, sql

I was just querying using my script on below:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(REG_DT, '%Y-%m-%d') DT2,
SUM(IF(CARRIER = '101' AND PROD_ID = 'ST', COUNT(DISTINCT MSISDN), 0)) "TSEL ST",
SUM(IF(CARRIER = '103' AND PROD_ID = 'ST', COUNT(DISTINCT MSISDN), 0)) "XL ST",
SUM(IF(CARRIER = '104' AND PROD_ID = 'ST', COUNT(DISTINCT MSISDN), 0)) "ISAT ST",
SUM(IF(CARRIER = '106' AND PROD_ID = 'ST', COUNT(DISTINCT MSISDN), 0)) "H3I ST",
SUM(IF(CARRIER = '105' AND PROD_ID = 'ST', COUNT(DISTINCT MSISDN), 0)) "SF ST",
SUM(IF(CARRIER = '101' AND PROD_ID = 'CN', COUNT(DISTINCT MSISDN), 0)) "TSEL CN",
SUM(IF(CARRIER = '103' AND PROD_ID = 'CN', COUNT(DISTINCT MSISDN), 0)) "XL CN",
SUM(IF(CARRIER = '104' AND PROD_ID = 'CN', COUNT(DISTINCT MSISDN), 0)) "ISAT CN",
SUM(IF(CARRIER = '106' AND PROD_ID = 'CN', COUNT(DISTINCT MSISDN), 0)) "H3I CN",
SUM(IF(CARRIER = '105' AND PROD_ID = 'CN', COUNT(DISTINCT MSISDN), 0)) "SF CN",
SUM(IF(CARRIER = '101' AND PROD_ID = 'DG', COUNT(DISTINCT MSISDN), 0)) "TSEL DG",
SUM(IF(CARRIER = '103' AND PROD_ID = 'DG', COUNT(DISTINCT MSISDN), 0)) "XL DG",
SUM(IF(CARRIER = '104' AND PROD_ID = 'DG', COUNT(DISTINCT MSISDN), 0)) "ISAT DG",
SUM(IF(CARRIER = '106' AND PROD_ID = 'DG', COUNT(DISTINCT MSISDN), 0)) "H3I DG",
SUM(IF(CARRIER = '105' AND PROD_ID = 'DG', COUNT(DISTINCT MSISDN), 0)) "SF DG",
SUM(IF(CARRIER = '101' AND PROD_ID = 'GM', COUNT(DISTINCT MSISDN), 0)) "TSEL GM",
SUM(IF(CARRIER = '103' AND PROD_ID = 'GM', COUNT(DISTINCT MSISDN), 0)) "XL GM",
SUM(IF(CARRIER = '104' AND PROD_ID = 'GM', COUNT(DISTINCT MSISDN), 0)) "ISAT GM",
SUM(IF(CARRIER = '106' AND PROD_ID = 'GM', COUNT(DISTINCT MSISDN), 0)) "H3I GM",
SUM(IF(CARRIER = '105' AND PROD_ID = 'GM', COUNT(DISTINCT MSISDN), 0)) "SF GM"
 FROM BGW_HIS_TB
WHERE REG_DT BETWEEN '2017-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-07-31 23:59:59'
  AND STATUS = 'S'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(REG_DT, '%Y-%m-%d') ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

When I try to run, it has errors:

> error code 1111. Invalid use of group function.

Those queries using table line_bgw.BGW_HIS_TB which column just like DATE, MSISDN, CARRIER, PROD_ID.

Comment: Can any of the below answers be accepted, Imam? It is not mandatory to accept or vote but it is certainly kind to the folks who helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest a `COUNT` inside a `SUM` argument.

Instead of this:

```
SUM(IF(CARRIER = '101' AND PROD_ID = 'ST', COUNT(DISTINCT MSISDN), 0))
```

Do:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(CARRIER = '101' AND PROD_ID = 'ST', MSISDN, NULL))
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(REG_DT, '%Y-%m-%d') as DT2,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN CARRIER = 101 AND PROD_ID = 'ST' THEN MSISDN) as "TSEL ST",
       . . .
FROM BGW_HIS_TB
WHERE REG_DT >= '2017-07-01' AND
      REG_DT < '2017-08-01' AND
      STATUS = 'S'
GROUP BY DT2
ORDER BY DT2;
```

Notes:

- I think you want `COUNT(DISTINCT)`, rather than `SUM()`.  That is a guess.
- I am guessing that status is a number not a string.  If so, it should be compared to a number.  Hence `101` rather than `'101'`.
- I simplified the date comparisons.  In general, `BETWEEN` is not wise to use with dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(REG_DT, '%Y-%m-%d') DT2,
SUM(CASE WHEN CARRIER = '101' AND PROD_ID = 'ST' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )'TSEL ST',
SUM(CASE WHEN CARRIER = '103' AND PROD_ID = 'ST' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )'XL ST'
 FROM BGW_HIS_TB
WHERE REG_DT BETWEEN '2017-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-07-31 23:59:59'
   AND STATUS = 'S'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(REG_DT, '%Y-%m-%d') ORDER BY 1 ASC;
create table BGW_HIS_TB (CARRIER varchar(255),PROD_ID varchar(255),MSISDN varchar(255),REG_DT date)
```

You can try above query.